# CakePHP 1.3.0 RC4 Installation

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-1.2, framework-installation

I have been using 1.2.6 and downloaded 1.3 to try it out. I am using wampserver with Apache 2.2.11. I have mod rewrite enabled. When I bake a new application using the cake 1.3 console, after I verify that the webroot/index.php of the application CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH is set to the Cake1.3 Installation folder. The result is a page thats missing CSS, missing a method. Typing in localhost/app/index.php will enable the program to find the app. Therefore I have to assume the rewrite module isnt functioning properly for v1.3. Is there something I have to add to the cake installation or app folder to make this function as it should?

Answer (score 0):

No, Cake is set up properly from the start. The thing that always trips me up is that I forget to set my Apache virtual host's `AllowOverride` value to `All`. This allows the `.htaccess` file to be read.

Comment: I set all the AllowOverride to "All" I still get the message:

Missing Method in AppController

Error: The action index is not defined in controller AppController

Comment: Ensure that your webroot is `<path to project>/app/webroot`. The .htaccess file in that directory should ignore files that already exist (like images, CSS, JS, etc.). The other .htaccess files redirect to that directory, but maybe something is getting lost in translation. It will also help if you can post your Apache config (hopefully a virtual host block).

Answer (score 0):

Are there any error messages in your apache error logs?

Did you replace the previous application's directory with the new one?  If not, you may need to add a  tag with the appropriate AllowOverride permissions set inside your httpd.conf file, to allow mod rewrite to execute.

Can you load /css/style.css in your browser or does it give a 404?

Comment: Error log reads:
[Tue Apr 20 10:05:03 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/wamp/www/css, referer: http://localhost/app/
[Tue Apr 20 10:05:03 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/wamp/www/img, referer: http://localhost/app/

The application I baked from scratch after I changed to environment varaibles to include the cake 1.3 console as opposed to the old one.
I replaced AllowOverride permissions in httpd.conf file with "All".

I cannot load the .css file in the browser. I get:
Missing Controller

Error: CssController could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

This may sound like a silly question, but after you made your changes to AllowOverride in your Apache configuration, did you restart Apache?